# $.ajax inside BeforeUpload Event - Plupload

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, amazon-s3, plupload

This app is an image uploading tool that uploads images directly from client browser to Amazon S3 using Plupload. So far, everything is working good except this issue.

I've this code for`BeforeUpload` event.

```
init: {
    BeforeUpload: function (up, file) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/ServerTime.ashx',
            dataType: 'text',
            data: { format: "yyyy-MM-dd_HH.mm.ss.fffffff" },
            type: 'POST',
            cache: false
        }).done(function (data) {
            console.log("Before setting ImageName: " + data);
            imageName = data + ".JPG";
            console.log("After setting ImageName: " + imageName);
            up.settings.multipart_params = {
                'key': key,
                'Filename': imageName,
                'acl': 'public-read',
                'success_action_status': '201',
                'AWSAccessKeyId': accessKey,
                'policy': policyDocument,
                'signature': policySignature
            };
        });
    }
}
```

However, I've this error when try to upload a file:

> HTTP Error. Upload URL might be wrong or doesn't exist.

On Console, it is printing the expected result as follows:

> Before setting ImageName: 2014-04-04_13.33.45.1155072
>
> After setting ImageName: 2014-04-04_13.33.45.1155072.JPG

I guess there is something wrong maybe because I'm using AJAX to get time from server. On the other  hand, trying the following code is working without any issue.

```
init: {
    BeforeUpload: function (up, file) {
        up.settings.multipart_params = {
            'key': "This_Is_Folder_Name/This_Is_File_Name.JPG",
            'Filename': "This_Is_File_Name.JPG",
            'acl': 'public-read',
            'success_action_status': '201',
            'AWSAccessKeyId': accessKey,
            'policy': policyDocument,
            'signature': policySignature
        };
    }
}
```

Notice that, this time I'm using static names for **Filename** and **key**, and there is no AJAX either

I really need help with this issue. Please suggest me. What I'm doing wrong with using AJAX to get server time and use it as file name?
Thanks.

Comment: Does the end of the 'key' have to match the 'imageName'?

Comment: Plupload is probably not expecting you to run asynchronous code in your BeforeUpload handler. It probably runs that function, and then uploads before your ajax comes back with results.

Comment: @Dov D, yes, end of `key` must match with file name. Actually `key` identifies to which directory of the `Bucket` a file should be uploaded.

Comment: @rescuecreative, my guess is similar too, however I've not found any document that specifies and proves that I cannot use `AJAX` inside the `BeforeUpload` event of the `Plupload`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might be able to override some of their code by doing the following:

```
init: {
    BeforeUpload: function (up, file) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/ServerTime.ashx',
            dataType: 'text',
            data: { format: "yyyy-MM-dd_HH.mm.ss.fffffff" },
            type: 'POST',
            cache: false
        }).done(function (data) {
            console.log("Before setting ImageName: " + data);
            imageName = data + ".JPG";
            console.log("After setting ImageName: " + imageName);
            up.settings.multipart_params = {
                'key': key,
                'Filename': imageName,
                'acl': 'public-read',
                'success_action_status': '201',
                'AWSAccessKeyId': accessKey,
                'policy': policyDocument,
                'signature': policySignature
            };
            file.status = plupload.UPLOADING;
            up.trigger("UploadFile", file);
        });
        return false;
    }
}
```

This would cancel their trigger, so you would have to trigger it yourself. Please note, I have not tested this.

**EDIT**: I'm not sure if `up` and `file` are out of scope though...

Comment: OMG. Awesome! Your untested code worked perfectly for me. :D Thank you.

Comment: Awesome answer! You save me my friend (y) ;)

Answer (score 3):

If you look in the Plupload source code you'll see this:

```
// Private methods
function uploadNext() {
    var file, count = 0, i;

    if (this.state == plupload.STARTED) {
        // Find first QUEUED file
        for (i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            if (!file && files[i].status == plupload.QUEUED) {
                file = files[i];
                if (this.trigger("BeforeUpload", file)) {
                    file.status = plupload.UPLOADING;
                    this.trigger("UploadFile", file);
                }
            } else {
                count++;
            }
        }

        // All files are DONE or FAILED
        if (count == files.length) {
            if (this.state !== plupload.STOPPED) {
                this.state = plupload.STOPPED;
                this.trigger("StateChanged");
            }
            this.trigger("UploadComplete", files);
        }
    }
}
```

The line that says `if (this.trigger("BeforeUpload", file)) {` will determine whether the return of the `trigger` call is truthy or falsy. If truthy, it will next trigger `"UploadFile"`. What that means is that the uploading of the file does not wait for asynchronous code to execute in your `BeforeUpload` function. As soon as that function returns, the upload can begin. Any async ajax call you make inside your `BeforeUpload` function will resolve after `"UploadFile"` is triggered.

Comment: Thanks. So no `AJAX` in `BeforeUpload` event. So what can you suggest me for this particular case? What I need is getting server time, setting it to file name before uploading images to Amazon. That is a `MUST` requirement for this app.

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing more of your architecture... Is it possible to upload to the server first, attach the info there, and then pass it along to Amazon?  If not, if you have some kind of "upload" button, maybe you could trap the click event on that button, run some ajax, then manually call Plupload after the ajax returns.

Comment: The current implementation of the app is like that. It interacts with server in order to upload the files to Amazon, and it also has an `Upload` button. But the purpose/requirement of the new implementation is removing server interacting and uploading files directly from the client browser. The only this I will interact with server is - (1) Getting the server time, (2) Inserting file information into database after file is uploaded, using the `FileUploaded` event of the Plupload.

Comment: Ok, in that case, I wouldn't tie Plupload into the upload button directly. I'd use jQuery or something like that to trap the click event on that button and make your ajax request. Once the ajax returns and you have all your data, I would call Plupload manually.